# How do I search the linux kernel mailing list archives?

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to research why a Linux kernel feature appears to be missing from my Linux install by searching the Linux kernel mailing list for recent discussions on the subject.  The only site that I've found that offers a search of the mailing list archives is [gmane](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel).  However, searching for terms with quotes (e.g., "/usr/firmware") on gmane does not restrict results to include only the quoted phrase.  Is there a more advanced search of the Linux kernel mailing list available?

Comment: Mailing lists are atrocious compared to bug trackers http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/191961/why-do-some-big-projects-like-git-and-debian-only-use-a-mailing-list-and-not-a

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [lkml.org](https://lkml.org/) to search through the archive. It's unofficial!

*excerpt*

> In case you haven't read the titlebar of your webbrowser's window:
>   this site is the (unofficial) Linux Kernel Mailing List archive. This
>   mailing list is a rather high-volume list, where (technical)
>   discussions on the design of, and bugs in the Linux kernel take place.
>   If that scares you, please [read the FAQ](http://www.tux.org/lkml/).

There are others as well:

- [Majordomo lists at VGER.KERNEL.ORG](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html)
- [The Linux-Kernel Archive - indiana.edu](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/)
- [Two digest forms of linux-kernel (a normal digest every 100KB and a once-daily digest)](http://lists.us.dell.com/)
- [Mailing list ARChives - MARC.info](http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel)

#### Tips for searching

If you drill in enough to the lkml.org site you'll find a search box, like here for example:

- https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/1/1

Additionally I would suggest leveraging the power of Google to help with this. Most of these types of sites suck in comparison as to what you can search with using Google.

For example:

Put this in your search bar if you want to find everything on lkml.org related to NFS!

```
site:https://lkml.org/ nfs
```

Comment: It scares all of us!

Comment: @Braiam - yeah I don't know why they say that...it's not that bad.

Comment: That's the one to sign up for if you want a personal message from Greg Kroah-Hartman telling you to "Go search the web or something". ;)

Comment: I haven't been able to find anywhere on lkml.org to _search_ the archives.  Majordomo doesn't seem to host any search/archives itself, just links to other archives.  The search on indiana.edu seems to be broken, I can't get any results for any search term.  The Dell site doesn't have the lkml archives, just Dell-specific mailing lists.  And the marc.info search suffers the same problem as the gmane one: it doesn't work with quoted phrases.  Additionally, it doesn't work with slashes in the search term.

Comment: @drs - see my updates

Comment: thanks, @slm, the google tip and the drilling down in lkml.org do exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: sometimes lkml.org show thread, but show empty emails in thread, like this: https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/8/12/532 .  But then such message possible to see via google groups interface: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=ru#!forum/linux.kernel

Comment: None of these suggestions actually work.  The drill-down only works for a subsection, and Google only returns a small fraction of the pages.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the places mentioned by slm, there's:

- [GMANE](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel)
- [The Mail Archive](http://www.mail-archive.com/linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org/)

Both of which are general services that include the linux kernel list.  The GMANE one has the most going for it -- click "Searching" in the side bar for an explanation of the features.

I'd love to say I knew an easy way to just download the entire archive so you could search it yourself, but I don't.  You could, however, put it together with a long series of automated requests (e.g. via curl) and some html scraping.

Comment: Thanks.  As I note in the question I find GMANE's search insufficient (on the "Searching" page you reference, they say that phrase searching is planned).  The Mail Archive worked pretty well, though the results were a bit inconsistent.  Nonetheless, this was a helpful link.

Answer (score 1):

While looking to download the archive I found this: https://github.com/patjenk/lkmlsentiment. I have not tried it yet.